# Finding windows update which contains a driver version

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, windows-update

How do you find which windows update contains a particular driver version?

I'm specifically looking for `usbhub.sys` `6.1.7601.22526`, i.e. the latest one on windows 7.

Googling shows KB2862330 might contain this, but it doesn't, it only has the catalog files.

The reason for this is since one of my windows updates (not sure which) wasn't installed properly, and windows shows no new updates despite my driver version being oudated. It's signature cannot be verified, since the catalog file went missing. I could manually add an old catalog file, but something else might break.

[EDIT] There's something strange going on, winsxs does have the latest version of this driver, but system32 has the older one. I'm hoping that re-installing the KB will fix this. Don't want to take the risk, as simply copying the files over manually might confuse windows.

Comment: Its a *tiny* bit risky, but offhand, wouldn't uninstalling the driver, and telling it to scan for drivers grab the latest off windows updates?

Comment: Search registry subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates` for valuedata `usbhub.sys`. Note: the subkey above is valid for Win-XP; in Win-7 could be the same...

Comment: @JosefZ Only have .net updates from there for some reason.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Does sound a bit risky, but this is the main usb driver, if I uninstall it the keyboard will stop working!

Comment: Why do you care if the USB driver is updated? If it's working why bother?

Comment: @Ramhound It's not working, it's signature cannot be verified because the cat file's gone.

Comment: If your keyboard is working though...

Comment: If you have a catalog problem.  SFC would be the solution.  Of course DISM within Windows 8.x+ would be very helpful it could "fix" your catalog files allowing SFC to repair the damage.

Comment: SFC can't fix it, the catalog is missing. But seriously, I wouldn't ask a question like that here unless I was grandma and needed to talk to "tech support".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the ideal solution. I realized that `KB2862330` actually did contain the driver files, they ended up in winsxs (which stores different driver versions) instead of System32, but this is useless, as the drivers are always loaded from System32.

For reasons unknown to me, the latest driver is not copied to System32. Normally `6.1.7601.22526` is not copied, instead `6.1.7601.18328` is which also came bundled with `KB2862330`. But this behaviour did not occur even though I uninstalled and reinstalled `KB2862330` 3 times.

At this point, it looked like to me that the only thing the install did not do was copy the driver files over, or at least I hoped. I just went ahead and copied them over.

Comment: the 22xx files are hotfix files, the 18xxx are the regular GDR files. Why do you need the hotfix version?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for telling me the difference, but niether the 18328 driver nor the 22526 was copied, the old one, v6.1.7601.17586 remained after reinstalling which was causing the problems. I copied 18328 which caused no problems.